# how to add 6 month and subtract date when setdate using JQXDateTimeInput

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a problem when using JQXDateTimeInput in javascript

i have a date using JQXDateTimeInput which element id = `datefrom`

and i want to change the other JQXDateTimeInput which element id = `dateto` 
when user changed `datefrom` by addition 6 month and subtract one day from `datefrom` that changed by user.

can some help me?
thanks

Comment: Do you mean [http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxdatetimeinput/index.htm](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxdatetimeinput/index.htm)?

Comment: yes, but i try to found way to add six month from the other element which is using jqxdatetomeinput too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I understand what you want ot do. You have to use their [API](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxdatetimeinput/jquery-datetimeinput-api.htm) to

1. catch [event](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxdatetimeinput/events.htm) of changing `#datefrom` with `valueChanged` for example
2. get selected date and add 6 month
3. assing new value with `value` property or `setDate` method to
   `#dateto`

So the full code

```
    // catch event ("change" event also works here)
    $('#datefrom').on('valueChanged', function (event) {  
        // get selected date
        var newDate = new Date(event.args.date); 
        // add 6 month
        newDate.setMonth(newDate.getMonth() + 6);
        // set another input's date
        $('#dateto').jqxDateTimeInput({value: newDate});
        // or
        // $('#dateto').jqxDateTimeInput('setDate', newDate);
    });
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/spakrdh9/)**